# Filter image by color range

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently testing differents methods to isolate a go board in an image (see example)
[image]

I have several ideas and one of them is to allow the user to select the color of the board and then filter the color in a certain range. Thus I tried the idea with OpenCV but maybe I have trouble understanding color spaces because my resulting image is all black.

Here is the code I used :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
img = cv2.imread(cv2.samples.findFile('data/go_board2.jpeg'))

# It converts the BGR color space of image to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_brown = np.array([34, 10, 95])
upper_brown = np.array([25, 49, 49])


# preparing the mask to overlay
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_brown, upper_brown)

# The black region in the mask has the value of 0,
# so when multiplied with original image removes all non-blue regions
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

  
cv2.imwrite("res/color/img.jpg", img)
cv2.imwrite("res/color/mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("res/color/result.jpg", result)
```

[34, 10, 95] is my light brown and [25, 49, 49] is the dark brown with [hue, saturation, value] but apparently that range is empty. How could I do to properly select the range I want (between the lighter and the darker brown of the board)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the lower limit has to be always lower than the upper limit, at the three channels. In your example, the lower hue and value are larger than the upper ones.

To define the limits, I recommend you to watch some of the images you have in HSV format using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, for instance, and see the values of each channel in the region of interest (board). I have done that with your image of example and used:

```
lower_limit=np.array([8, 10, 0])
upper_limit=np.array([20, 140, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_limit, upper_limit)
```

It has worked decently:

[image: Board image result]

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I could efficiently detect the board using another technique on the new image ?

Comment: welcome. that's a new and separate question. [ask].